# Como passar props para o estado em React

Tags: react

Boa tarde. Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo de calculadora com React. Eu gostaria de saber como passar o valor de uma propriedade de um dos meus botões para o valor do state.

Por exemplo: botão 7, passa o seu value 7 para o this.state.result.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      result: 0,
      number: 0      
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(){
    this.setState({
      result: this.props.value
    })
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button className="result">{this.state.result}</button>
        <button value="0">AC</button>
        <button>+/-</button>
        <button>%</button>
        <button className="opBut">/</button>
        <button value="7" onClick={this.handleClick}>7</button>
        <button value="8">8</button>
        <button value="9">9</button>
        <button className="opBut">X</button>
        <button value="4">4</button>
        <button value="5">5</button>
        <button value="6">6</button>
        <button className="opBut">-</button>
        <button value="1">1</button>
        <button value="2">2</button>
        <button value="3">3</button>
        <button className="opBut">+</button>
        <button value="0" className="button0">0</button>
        <button>.</button>
        <button className="opBut">=</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Formata seu código para podermos entender e cadê o botão no render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a ideia for efetuar a leitura do atributo `value` do botão clicado basta utilizar o `event.target.value`:

```
handleClick(){
  const valBotaoClicado = event.target.value;
  this.setState({
    result: valBotaoClicado
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa necessariamente declarar uma função para atualizar um estado.

Por exemplo, uma entrada de dados pode ser atualizada assim que houver alguma alteração utilizando o [onChange()](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html):

```
<input value={this.state.value}  onChange={(value) => this.setState({valor: value})} />
```

E caso você queira trabalhar com alguma ação desses estados você pode criar uma função (fazendo o [Bind](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) dela obviamente) que trabalhe com os valores que você quer.